# Square API responds with empty JSON

Tags: square-connect

Why am I receiving an empty response from the Square server?

I can't seem to get any sort of response once I change the location to one of the test locations. I'm using the correct sandbox token. Have I unintentionally omitted necessary information or triggered some sort of bug or security mechanism? I can not imagine an empty response being appropriate in any circumstance. Sensitive strings obfuscated for obvious reasons.

**PHP**

```
$url = 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/'.$location_id.'/transactions';
$curl_handle = curl_init($url);
$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$request_headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token;
$encodedData = json_encode($jsonData);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encodedData);
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Length: '.strlen($encodedData);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
```

**JSON used in cURL Request**

```
{
"idempotency_key": "1",
"billing_address": {
"address_line_1": "123 Main Street",
"address_line_2": "",
"locality": "New York City",
"administrative_district_level_1": "NY",
"postal_code": "12345",
"country": "US"
},
"amount_money": {
"amount": 10,
"currency": "USD"
},
"delay_capture": false,
"buyer_email_address": "test@example.com",
"card_nonce": "122333444455555666666777777"
}
```

Using `print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_handle))` I receive:

```
Array
(
 [certinfo] => Array()
 [connect_time] => 0.101375
 [content_type] => application/json
 [download_content_length] => 2
 [filetime] => -1
 [header_size] => 372
 [http_code] => 200
 [local_ip] => 66.198.240.51
 [local_port] => 44428
 [namelookup_time] => 0.009074
 [pretransfer_time] => 0.392582
 [primary_ip] => 74.122.190.85
 [primary_port] => 443
 [redirect_count] => 0
 [redirect_time] => 0
 [redirect_url] => 
 [request_size] => 734
 [size_download] => 2
 [size_upload] => 492
 [speed_download] => 3
 [speed_upload] => 979
 [ssl_verify_result] => 0
 [starttransfer_time] => 0.502108
 [total_time] => 0.502167
 [upload_content_length] => 492
 [url] => https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/__example__/transactions
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there are reason why you aren't using the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk)? I think that would make this a little easier for you, keeping track of all these curl options looks kind of confusing.

You are sending a `GET` request to the transactions endpoint asking the API to list all your transactions. For `GET` requests, adding a body to your requests is not a good idea since it is ignored by nearly every API out there (like ours).

The API receives your `GET` request and returns to you your transactions which you probably haven't created any in your testing account likely looks like:

```
{}
```

This is the expected behavior. If you are trying to create a charge and not list your transactions, send a `POST` request instead, or just use the SDK to make things easier on you, see [Charge](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/docs/Api/TransactionsApi.md#charge)

Comment: I'm now getting (vague) error messages though that *did* fix the problem. I *really* dislike third party code as it's usually bloated and convoluted. I've got what I hope to be the last question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477085/square-value-was-not-expected-to-be-a-string and if I can get this working I'll be absolutely thrilled.

Comment: Also, looking at the SDK (to hopefully distill the JSON I need) it says to use `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` however there is no vendor directory in the SDK. So...what?

Comment: You have to use composer, the package manager for PHP, read the installation instructions on this page: https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk

Comment: Ah, this is why I distill everything. Once I've minimized the code where would be a good place to share what I've learned? I like everything about Square thus far except it is a bit unorganized for someone who avoids third party software. People don't understand this until I show them websites loading eight megabytes of JavaScript. It's all about my clients and for them it's all about their clients. I'll mess with composer and hopefully get far enough to work unimpeded through the night. I appreciate your help and responses!