# Square: Value was not expected to be a string

Tags: square-connect

I'm getting a "Value was not expected to be a string" error. I've validated the JSON request with a validator and I've ensured that all values are enclosed within double quotes. However when it tells me the length (in this example, 500) it is greater than the length of the JSON itself.

```
[category] => INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR
[code] => BAD_REQUEST
[detail] => Value was not expected to be a string (line 1, character 500)
```

Using:

```
{
"idempotency_key": "1",
"billing_address": {
"address_line_1": "123 Main Street",
"address_line_2": "",
"locality": "New York City",
"administrative_district_level_1": "NY",
"postal_code": "12345",
"country": "US"
},
"amount_money": {
"amount": "10",
"currency": "USD"
},
"delay_capture": "false",
"buyer_email_address": "someone@example.com",
"card_nonce": "C257wsh4fggd1OWEQLTwU0MIdnA"
}
```

This error message is too vague. How do I convert the unknown variable from a string to the unknown desired data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to specify the `amount` in `amount_money` as a string instead of a number, same thing for `delay_capture`. try

```
"amount": 10,
"delay_capture": false,
```

I agree, the error message is a little confusing, I'll see if I can get it improved.

Comment: I tried that. I was trying to get a *raw* dump of the JSON code to determine where the value was (editor will tell you what character number you're at if you remove all line breaks). I've *added* extra characters to "feel" around by changing the 500 however it won't change (I removed the quotes from the amount value, obviously). I'm having issues with composer ("Could not open input file: composer.phar") so getting *that* running to look at the generated JSON isn't an option, at least right now (can't figure that issue out either).

Comment: `delay_capture` was also wrong, just updated the answer.

Comment: That edit *sort* of helped, it moved the error character position to 478. I have a private URL I can share with all the data if that would help?

Comment: Hey, I figured out the last remaining bit, double-encoded JSON. Left the answer below too in case someone dealt with the issues trying to distill the code as well.

Answer (score 1):

A secondary issue: if the data is *already formatted as JSON **ensure that the JSON is not being encoded a second time**!*

```
//$encodedData = json_encode($json);//double-encoded code issue here!
$encodedData = $json;
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encodedData);
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Length: '.strlen($encodedData);
```